# calcru: runtime went backwards (FreeBSD)

Tags: freebsd, kvm-virtualization

I have installed a fresh FreeBSD 9.1 machine running in a virtual KVM environment. After some days of uptime I always see the following messages for various PIDs in the system console:

```
calcru: runtime went backwards
```

After searching in Google I found [this thread](http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=2805), which is on the same issue. However, even after trying all tips given in that thread the problem still occurs on my machine. Interestingly however, as said, only after some days of uptime.

I tried the following already:

- `sysctl kern.timecounter.hardware=i8254`
- `sysctl kern.timecounter.hardware=TSC`
- `kern.hz="100"` in `/boot/loader.conf`
- `debug.acpi.disabled="timer"` in `/boot/loader.conf`
- Other NTP servers for my local ntpd

However, none of these things helped.

Any other ideas?

Comment: The advice you're reading is stale (See the linked duplicate: there are other things you need to do in 9.x). It's also possible your VM is just so lousy at keeping time that you'll never get it to work correctly -- in that case you can just ignore the messages (they're annoying, but *usually* harmless - they just screw up resource usage statistics.)